# Node not moving?

Tags: key, shapes

Here I created a simple pane with a circle dead in the center. I have created buttons that move the circle but got rid of them to create key events instead. I am wondering why is it when I press the keys that would trigger the circle to move nothing happens. I am trying to move the circle in the direction of the arrow pressed yet nothing is going on. An explanation as to why this is would be great.

```
package circlekeyevent;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CircleKeyEvent extends Application {

  @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        final Circle circle = new Circle(250, 250, 20);
        circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Move the circle"); 
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
        primaryStage.show();

        //Key Events
     class MoveLeft implements EventHandler <KeyEvent>{
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e){
              if ((e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT && (circle.getCenterX() >= 5))) {

                 circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX()-5);       
            }
        }             
      }     
     class MoveRight implements EventHandler <KeyEvent>{
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e){
            if ((e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) && (circle.getCenterX() <= scene.getWidth() - 5)) {
                 circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX()+5);       
            }
        }       
    }     
         class MoveUp implements EventHandler <KeyEvent>{
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e){
               if ((e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) && (circle.getCenterY() >= 5)) {
                 circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY()-5);       
            }
        }     
      }        
         class MoveDown implements EventHandler <KeyEvent>{
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e){
               if ((e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN && (circle.getCenterY() <= scene.getHeight() - 5))) {
                 circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY()+5);       
            }
        }     
      }       
    circle.setOnKeyPressed(new MoveLeft());
    circle.setOnKeyPressed(new MoveRight());
    circle.setOnKeyPressed(new MoveUp());
    circle.setOnKeyPressed(new MoveDown());
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

 }
```

Comment: If you have any questions or if my answer needs improvement just comment and I will get back to you

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I made some minor changes and now it is working as intended.

Comment: I did notice an error when moving left(It goes off screen) so I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend combining all of the methods for movement and using a text field for keyboard commands. Setting the opacity low makes the text field invisible and bringing it to back makes it to that it wont cover anything up.
Here is the code that I would recommend using:

```
package circlekeyevent;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CircleKeyEvent extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    TextField textfield =new TextField();
    textfield.setOpacity(0.0000001);

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    final Circle circle = new Circle(250, 250, 20);
    circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    pane.getChildren().add(circle);
    pane.getChildren().add(textfield);
    textfield.toBack();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Move the circle"); 
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
    primaryStage.show();

    //Key Events     
 class Move implements EventHandler <KeyEvent>{
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent e){
        if ((e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) && (circle.getCenterX() <= scene.getWidth() - 5)) {
             circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX()+5);       
        } else if ((e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) && (circle.getCenterX() >= 5)) {
            circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX()-5);       
       } else if ((e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) && (circle.getCenterY() >= 5)) {
           circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY()-5);       
      } else if ((e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN && (circle.getCenterY() <= scene.getHeight() - 5))) {
          circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY()+5);       
     }
    }       
}                    
textfield.setOnKeyPressed(new Move());
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

You can also add a set cursor if nothing is placed over top of the text field

Here is the cursor code:

```
textfield.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
```